# What's the best way to generate a Word document from a Word template in PHP?

Tags: php, ms-word, labeling

I have a template for a style of Avery stationery in a Word document. What I'd like to do is fill in the template with images (in this case, QR codes) for easy printing and labeling of objects.

I'm wondering, what would be the easiest way to do this? I saved the template as a Word XML file, but looking at the file, I feel hopeless. I also tried converting the template to HTML, but unsuprisingly it screwed up the formatting. I'm not sure where to go next, any ideas?

Comment: If you're on a Windows host, you can control Word directly via DCOM. Remember that Office is really just a huge set of libraries and some front-end implementations that happen to be word processors, spreadsheets, etc...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of good options out there to do this. I would recommend [PHP LiveDocX](http://www.phplivedocx.org/) (free) or [PHP DocX](http://www.phpdocx.com/) (free basic version).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the PHP Class, [MsDoc Generator](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2631-PHP-Create-Microsoft-Word-document-without-COM-objects.html). It will let you create and add elements (text, tables, images) dynamically.